# i want to create a quiz question using a text box

Tags: javascript, html

so i want to make a text box quiz question using a text and submit button in html that then sends it to a javascript file to check if its the right answer.

i tried using a get.elementbyid for the answer of what they put in than an if else statement to check if it was the right answer.
the code i used:
the html code(just the part that i mainly want to use):

```
<div>
  <label for="answer">answer</label>
  <input name="answer"  type="text">
  <input id="answer" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="answer()">
</div>


  
 <script src="puzzle2.js">

 </script>
```

the javascript code:

```
var uInp = document.getElementById("answer");

function answer() {
  if (uInp == "ok") {
    alert("correct");
  }else{
    alert("incorrect");
  };
};
```

Comment: i messed up but i fixed it. i was working on python a bit ago so i got confused and mixed them up

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. `uInp` is the *button*, not the *text input*
2. `uInp == "ok"` will *never* be true, because `uInp` is the *element*, not its *value*

Let's move the `id` to the text input and test against the `.value` property:

```js
var uInp = document.getElementById("answer");

function answer() {
  if (uInp.value == "ok") {
    alert("correct");
  }else{
    alert("incorrect");
  };
};
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="answer">answer</label>
  <input id="answer" name="answer" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="answer()">
</div>
```

You can also take it a step further and get rid of the inline `onclick`, replacing it with `addEventListener`:

```js
var uInp = document.getElementById("answer");

function answer() {
  if (uInp.value == "ok") {
    alert("correct");
  }else{
    alert("incorrect");
  };
};

document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', answer);
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="answer">answer</label>
  <input id="answer" name="answer" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: so i just wanted to ask, what dose/is the .value after the uInp for and mean

Comment: @DavidMcCleary: It's [the value of the input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value).  Otherwise you're comparing the string `"ok"` with *the entire element*, and an HTML element is a complex object, not just a string.